# Get Unique Record In Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am Using a Stored Procedure in which I am getting some record and Want to filter these record By `null` value, True and false

[image]

Here in this table I want only the record where `PlanIsValid` is 1 or NULL
Here Is my Query

```
Select ui.ID,sp.PlanName, sp.PlanIsValid 
from Usersinfo ui 
left join SubscriptionPlan sp on ui.ID = sp.UserID
```

Comment: So add a WHERE clause that makes an effort to do so. We'll wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `where` clause :

```
Select ui.ID,sp.PlanName, sp.PlanIsValid 
from Usersinfo ui 
left join SubscriptionPlan sp on ui.ID = sp.UserID 
where sp.PlanIsValid is null or sp.PlanIsValid = 1;
```

However, if you want to get the `ID`s which are not present in `SubscriptionPlan` table the you can use `NOT EXISTS` instead

```
select ui.ID
from Usersinfo ui 
where not exists (select 1 
                  from SubscriptionPlan sp
                  where ui.ID = sp.UserID 
                 );
```